# Weka library for iOS

Tags: ios, weka

can you please tell me if there is a `weka` (machine learning algorithm) for `iOS` ?
and if yes then provide me with a download link to download it.

Answer (score 1):

iOS Agreement says:

"3.3.2 — An Application may not itself install or launch other executable code by any means, including without limitation through the use of a plug-in architecture, calling other frameworks, other APIs or otherwise. No interpreted code may be downloaded or used in an Application except for code that is interpreted and run by Apple’s Documented APIs and built-in interpreter(s)."

So you cannot lanch a java interpreter to use WEKA libraries.

BUT... Google released a "Java to iOS Objective C translator" a few days ago. And WEKA is an "Open Source" project. So, maybe, you could try to download WEKA's (java) code and translate it from java to Objective-C in order to run WEKA's algorithms in iOS.
If you get it, please, let me know ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Weka is written in Java. This means the likelihood of it being adapted to iOS is quite small.